# how do I find the non-numerical mode while filtering two other columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Say I have a personal spreadsheet of who worked at certain locations and on what date. Column A is dates, Column B is locations, and Column C is names. I want to create a function that takes a year and location as inputs, searches Column C, and will return the most common occurring name for the given year and location.

| Dates | Locations | Names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | New York | Bart |
| 01/02/2020 | New York | Bart |
| 01/03/2020 | Chicago | Kate |
| 01/04/2020 | Chicago | Kate |
| 01/05/2020 | Chicago | John |
| 01/01/2022 | Seattle | Kate |
| 01/02/2022 | Seattle | Mark |
| 01/03/2022 | New York | Bart |
| 01/04/2022 | Seattle | Mark |
| 01/05/2022 | New York | Bart |
| 01/06/2022 | New York | Kate |

For example:
=function(2020, 'Chicago') returns Kate

=function(2022, 'New York') returns Bart

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,ifna(filter(C:C,year(A:A)=E1,B:B=F1)),
       +sort(map(unique(Σ),lambda(Λ,{Λ,countif(Σ,Λ)})),2,))
```

[image]